# A multivariable polynomial degree question

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Given $\mathsf{F,G}\in\Bbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, minimum multivariate polynomials of least total degree $\mathsf{degF}$, $\mathsf{degG}$ such that, given unequal $a,b\in\Bbb R$,
$$\mathsf{F(p)}=a, \mathsf{G(p)}\neq b,\mbox{ }\forall\mathsf{p}\in\mathsf{S_F},$$ 
$$\mathsf{F(p)}\neq a, \mathsf{G(p)}=b,\mbox{ }\forall\mathsf{p}\in\mathsf{S_G},$$ 
$$\mathsf{S_F}\cap\mathsf{S_G}=\emptyset,\mbox{ }\mathsf{S_F}\cup\mathsf{S_G}=\{\mathsf{-m,+m}\}^n,\mbox{ }m\in\Bbb R\backslash\{0\}.$$

Denote $$\Delta(p)=\{\mathsf{q}\in\{\mathsf{-2m,0,+2m}\}^n: \|\mathsf{q}\|_2^2=2m,\mbox{ }\mathsf{p+q}\in\{\mathsf{-m,+m}\}^n\},$$

$$\max_{\forall\mathsf{p}\in\mathsf{S_F}}|\Delta(\mathsf{p})\cap\mathsf{S_G}|=\mathsf{\delta_F},$$
$$\max_{\forall\mathsf{p}\in\mathsf{S_G}}|\Delta(\mathsf{p})\cap\mathsf{S_F}|=\mathsf{\delta_G}.$$

Does there exist universal $\mathsf{c\geq1}$ such that $$\mathsf{\max}(\mathsf{degF},\mathsf{degG})\mathsf{\leq}\big(\mathsf{\max}(\mathsf{\delta_F},\mathsf{\delta_G})\big)^{\mathsf{c}}$$ holds true?